# Turning part of the pages

Tags: rotating

I have several chapters in a thesis lay-out. I would like to turn the last chapter by 180 degrees, so you can read it from the back of the book (some kind of flip book idea - turning book for children). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Print as normal and then physically rearrange the sheets?

Comment: pdfpages might do it after the file has been formatted normally.

Comment: I am affraid 'print as normal' is not really an option for a thesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pdfpages package did the trick :)

I used:
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

In combination with:
\includepdf[pages=last-1,angle=180]{Name of the pdf file}